# traversing through an array with nested loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've never really understood multi dimensional arrays and how to move through them until recently.

so far, I've figured out how to go through a 2D array horizontally, vertically and diagonally automatically without hardcoding any numbers on a simple function to help me understand nested loops better.

an array is created with all the possible sequences, but it's the diagonal on the right (3,5,7) that I can't seem to conceptualize how to loop to and through.

any pointers?

is there a smarter way of doing all this?

```js
const grid = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
]

const coordinates = grid => {
  const arr = [];

  // get horizontals
  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
      arr.push(grid[i][j]);
      // horizontals
      // grid[i][j]
      // grid[0][0]
      // grid[0][1]
      // grid[0][2]
      // grid[1][0]
      // grid[1][1]
      // grid[1][2]
      // grid[2][0]
      // grid[2][1]
      // grid[2][2]
    }
  }

  // get verticals
  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
      arr.push(grid[j][i]);
      // verticals
      // grid[j][i]
      // grid[0][0]
      // grid[1][0]
      // grid[2][0]
      // grid[0][1]
      // grid[1][1]
      // grid[2][1]
      // grid[0][2]
      // grid[1][2]
      // grid[2][2]
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
      if (i === j) arr.push(grid[i][j])
      // grid[0][0]
      // grid[1][1]
      // grid[2][2]
    }
  }

  console.log(arr)
}

coordinates(grid);
```

Comment: grid[i][grid.length - i - 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for diag.

```
for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
  // grid[i][i]
}
```

You can traverse the 4 diagonals by using grid.length-1-i for various indexes.

```
  // grid[grid.length-1-i][i] // etc...
```

This will give you 3,5,7

```
  // grid[i][grid.length-1-i] // etc...
```

Comment: It should be a `;` instead of a `,` in your `for` statement.

Comment: that magic value of length-1-i, how did you come up with that?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I need to stop answering questions that need code on my phone...  Thanks!

Comment: how do I get 159 with this?

Comment: grid[i][i] will return 0,0 1,1 and 2,2